# Creating random password

Tags: bash, password

I need to create passwords on the fly from a script.

Unfortunately I cannot use applications that utilize /dev/urandom because of the time it takes to create the password.

Are there other applications that I can use to create passwords on the fly?

Comment: They all use `/dev/urandom`. Unless they use `/dev/random`, which is even slower.

Comment: You can't both have your cake and eat it. If you don't need the passwords to be random, use `swordfish` everywhere. If you do need the passwords to be random, `/dev/urandom` is as fast as it gets (unlike `/dev/random` which may block).

Comment: How many passwords do you need in so short of a time that `/dev/urandom` is too slow?

Comment: `cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9-_!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:<>?='  | fold -w 12 | head -n 4` takes about .01 seconds... If you need something faster, you will probably need to write your own program.

Comment: More thought... perhaps your /dev/urandom is using /dev/random for some reason? Try `cat /dev/urandom`. If it's REALLY slow, and pauses when you don't move the mouse for a while, it's probably using /dev/random for some reason

Comment: @Hyppy that command did it.

Comment: Woot. I'll add it as an answer then.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101362/how-do-you-generate-passwords

Comment: "Nine nine nine nine nine nine nine nine..." http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/wp-content/uploads/121411_1611_SecureRando1.png

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently this answer worked:

```
cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9-_!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:<>?=' | fold -w 12 | head -n 4
```

... takes about .01 seconds.

Comment: < /dev/urandom tr [...] will be even faster.

Answer (score 4):

The [apg](http://www.adel.nursat.kz/apg/) tool is kinda dated but still good for password generation. It supports sizing the passwords, password checking with dictionaries, generation of pronounceable or random passwords, has a built-in PRNG and `/dev/random` support and can generate various passwords on a bunch or on a shell script.

Examples:

```
# apg -c random_seed 
dordififId
riHegyipju
Noafrathvu
IchJinCet
utadwulb
ethFench
```

Generate only one with no delimiter:

```
# apg -c random_seed -n 1 -d
AkKijNayn
```

Spell the generated passwords:

```
# apg -c random_seed -n 1 -d
aicWajbyRorp42863:~# apg -c random_seed -l
FrogQuev Foxtrot-romeo-oscar-golf-Quebec-uniform-echo-victor
cecNeiv1 charlie-echo-charlie-November-echo-india-victor-ONE
SkudVolt Sierra-kilo-uniform-delta-Victor-oscar-lima-tango
TowUlripab Tango-oscar-whiskey-Uniform-lima-romeo-india-papa-alfa-bravo
Bytquigpey Bravo-yankee-tango-quebec-uniform-india-golf-papa-echo-yankee
Doithneb Delta-oscar-india-tango-hotel-november-echo-bravo
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try 'pwgen' (available in Ubuntu/Debian/Gentoo etc.)

Generate a 10 char password:

```
pwgen 10
```

Generate a more secure 10 char password:

```
pwgen -s 10
```

Generate a 'really' secure 10 char password:

```
pwgen -sy 10
```

Hope this helps,
Cheers

Comment: `pwgen` uses `/dev/urandom` as well

Answer (score 2):

The following generates a unique 8 lower and upper character password:
`openssl rand -base64 6`

Answer (score 1):

```
mkpasswd -l 10
# will make a randon password with 10 chars - you may need to install it ...
```

Comment: `mkpasswd` uses `/dev/urandom`.

Comment: then make your own random  ... like reading the clock then search some files ... sorry can't think of a faster way - one problem that you may have into the system is that you don't have enough entropy

Answer (score 0):

```
#Chars allowed in password (I don't like l,o,O, etc):
P="0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnpqrstuvwxyz"

#Or such:
#P="a-zA-Z0-9"

#The string pasted as $P$P$P... must be at least 256 chars long.

head -c 8 < /dev/urandom | tr '\000-\377' "$P$P$P$P$P"
echo
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating a password a human should remember, pick a few random words from a dictionary:

`$ uniq < /usr/share/dict/words | shuf | head -n 4 | tr '\n' ' '
reinitialise content snug dimly`

[Relevant XKCD strip](https://xkcd.com/936/)

Comment: I like this one.